# Datastore: Saving entity with successors in the same transaction with autogenerated key Ids

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I'd like to run the following algorithm (it's more like javascript pseudocode)

```
const transaction = datastore.transaction(); 
await transaction.run();
const parentKey = createKey(namespace, kind) // note that I leave the ID th be generated
await transaction.save(ancestorKey, parentEntity); 
const childKey = createKey(namepsace, kind, parentId, parentKind) // ??? 
await transaction.save (ChildKey, childEntity); 
await transaction.commit();
```

How can I know the parentId since the initial save of parentEntity is not yet commited?

I'd like to run this into a single transaction, is this achievable?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible due to the datastore's [transaction isolation and consistency](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#isolation_and_consistency) (emphasis mine):

> This consistent snapshot view also extends to reads after writes
>   inside transactions. Unlike with most databases, queries and gets
>   inside a Cloud Datastore transaction do not see the results of
>   previous writes inside that transaction. Specifically, if an entity is
>   modified or deleted within a transaction, a query or lookup returns
>   the *original* version of the entity as of the beginning of the
>   transaction, **or nothing if the entity did not exist then**.

Depending on why you actually *need* such sequence to be done transactionally you *might* be able to achieve something somehow equivalent this way:

- create the parent transactionally
- in the same transaction also create and [transactionally enqueue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/transactions#transactional_task_enqueuing) a push task queue passing it the parent's key as parameter - the task will be enqueued only if/when the transaction succeeds
- in the task handler (also made transactional) create the child entity - guaranteed to only happen once

Note that not all GAE environments support such scheme due to limited push task queue support.